# No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven

Возникает ошибка `No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?` при Maven install, при этом даже переменную среду создал. IDE: Eclipse for EE.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>growthing-02</groupId>
<artifactId>growthing-02</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>growthing-02 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <!--spring version-->
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <!--mybatis version-->
    <mybatis.version>3.2.6</mybatis.version>
    <!--log4j version-->
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>junit</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>junit</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>4.12</version>-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;This means it will be loaded only under development&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <!--spring core jars-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--mybatis core jars-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--spring-mybatis-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--java ee-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--postgresql db-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--dbcp jar, using for configuring db information in applicationContext.xml-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL tag jar-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--log-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--format log-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--jason-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <!--<finalName>main</finalName>-->
    <plugins>
        <!--<plugin>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<source>1.7</source>-->
                <!--<target>1.7</target>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
        <!--</plugin>-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>main</warName>
                <outputDirectory>D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!--<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>-->
</build>
```

Я даже прямо указывал

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.9</source>
        <target>1.9</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Тот же результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window -> Preferences - > Java -> 
Раскрыть Installes JREs кликнуть Execution Environments далее в открывшемся списке 
кликнуть JavaSE-1.8(или какая там у вас) 
Далее поставить галочку где jdk вместо jre.

Comment: jre-9.0.4 (default) стоит.

Comment: Т.е. это не помогло.

Comment: "Далее поставить галочку где jdk вместо jre." - там только jre-9.0.4 (default) доступно.

Comment: Подключил JDK, помогло. Спасибо.